# move DHCP service to another windows server seamlessly?

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server

i've searched similar answers on serverfault and google but i need to clarify the procedure to do this.

i have a old windows server 2012 which provides dhcp service and now want to transfer this dhcp service to another new windows server(server 2016) seamlessly without interrupting the service.

i'm following this [post](http://www.ngcci.com/move-dhcp-one-server-another-dhcp-server/)'s instructions to perform the migration of dhcp and i would like to know:

1. is this instruction fine for my demand?
2. when i'm using command "netsh dhcp server" to migration the dhcp, will the dhcp service on the new server conflict to the old dhcp service? i guess they will both exist in a short period of time before i deactivate and remove the dhcp on old server.

i can't take the risk when migrating DHCP service with interruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the directions there I would slightly modify the order.

You can install the DHCP service on the new server before you do the export.  I think you should do this first to minimize the time between your export/import process.

I would probably also do an export on the old server, then deactivate the scopes, or stop/disable the DHCP service. After that you can import the database on the new server.

If you want to minimize outages, have a longer lease time during the transition (3+days), and do your transition at a time when computers aren't restarting, or connecting to your network. A DHCP server being offline for a while usually doesn't hurt anything as long as computers have active leases.  Your only problem is with computers that restart or connect to the network while the DHCP server is being transitioned.

For best results have a few devices handy to test DHCP renewals after you transition.